# save page rank output in neo4j

Tags: scala, neo4j, spark-graphx

I am running Pregel Page rank algorith
m on twitter data in Spark using scala. The algorithm runs fine and gives me the output correctly finding out the highest page rank score. But I am unable to save graph on neo4j.

The inputs and outputs are mentioned below.

**Input file:** (The numbers are twitter userIDs)

```
86566510 15647839
86566510 197134784
86566510 183967095
15647839 11272122
15647839 10876852
197134784 34236703
183967095 20065583
11272122 197134784
34236703 18859819
20065583 91396874
20065583 86566510
20065583 63433165
20065583 29758446
```

**Output of the graph vertices:**

```
(11272122,0.75)
(34236703,1.0)
(10876852,0.75)
(18859819,1.0)
(15647839,0.6666666666666666)
(86566510,0.625)
(63433165,0.625)
(29758446,0.625)
(91396874,0.625)
(183967095,0.6666666666666666)
(197134784,1.1666666666666665)
(20065583,1.0)
```

Using the below scala code I try saving the graph but it does'nt. Please help me solve this.

```
Neo4jGraph.saveGraph(sc, pagerankGraph, nodeProp = "twitterId", relProp = "follows")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! pls. provide exception details if you have.is it `org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Failed to establish connection with server.` how are you running  your program? pls provide complete details

Comment: val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "D:\\Code\\scalaworkspace\\GraphAlgorithms\\resources\\twitter-graph-data-sample.txt")
val initialGraph = graph
   .outerJoinVertices(graph.outDegrees) {
    (vertexId, vdata, deg) => deg.getOrElse(0)
   }.mapTriplets( e => 1.0)
   .mapVertices((id, attr) => attr.toDouble)
   /** Run algo on initialGraph  **/
val pagerankGraph: Graph[Double, Double] = Pregel(initialGraph, initialMessage, numIterations)(
       vertexProgram, sendMessage, messageCombiner)
Neo4jGraph.saveGraph(sc, pagerankGraph, nodeProp = "twitterId", relProp = "follows")

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the graph originally from Neo4j? Currently saveGraph saves the graph data back to Neo4j nodes via their internal id's.

It actually runs this statement:

```
UNWIND {data} as row 
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = row.id 
SET n.$nodeProp = row.value return count(*)
```

But as a short term mitigation I added optional labelIdProp parameters that are used instead of the internal id's, and a match/merge flag. You'll have to build the library yourself though to use that. I gonna push the update the next few days.

Something you can try is `Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList`

Here is the test code for it.

You basically have a dataframe with the data and it saves it to a Neo4j graph (including relationships though).

```
    val rows = sc.makeRDD(Seq(Row("Keanu", "Matrix")))
    val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType), StructField("title", DataTypes.StringType)))
    val df = new SQLContext(sc).createDataFrame(rows, schema)
    Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList(sc, df, ("Person",Seq("name")),("ACTED_IN",Seq.empty),("Movie",Seq("title")))
    val edges : RDD[Edge[Long]] = sc.makeRDD(Seq(Edge(0,1,42L)))
    val graph = Graph.fromEdges(edges,-1)
    assertEquals(2, graph.vertices.count)
    assertEquals(1, graph.edges.count)
    Neo4jGraph.saveGraph(sc,graph,null,"test")

    val it: ResourceIterator[Long] = server.graph().execute("MATCH (:Person {name:'Keanu'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie {title:'Matrix'}) RETURN count(*) as c").columnAs("c")
    assertEquals(1L, it.next())
    it.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I dont originally load the data from neo4j. I read from a flatfile using spark, do the algorithm and save the output in neo4j.